# Splitting strings in an array to another array, and then refrenceing them for calculations

Tags: c#, arrays, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I am still currently learning the ropes with C# and I need some help. So I have a text file that contains a total of 9 lines like so:

```
inch,.083333
fathom,6
foot,1
furlong,660
kilometer,3281.5
meter,3.2815
mile,5280
rod,16.5
yard,3
```

I used the method "ReadAllLines" to create an array called lengths. Then in the "form load" section, i created a loop that would split the string in each line and output each of the Units of measure to a list box. This was necessary so that when the user opens the form, they can select a number from 1 - 9 that will reference each unit of measure. Now here is where i begin having my issue. Once the user presses the calculate button, before anything else is done, i set up a while loop to split the strings in the lengths array to obtain the numerical values of each of the units of measure in each line, convert each value to a double, and then to dump this information into a new array called units. The purpose of this program is for users to be able to convert units of measurement to different units of measurements that they select. I want to be able to do the calculations using the numerical values from the array called units which came from the split method from the first array. I know i can do this by specifically indicating the index on the new array, I.E.: units[1] and then do my calculations.  Now when i go to run the program, it always hangs up saying that the "Index was outside the bounds of the Array". I know that the index refers to the memory location in the array, so the index cannot be greater than the array, so im not entirely sure what i am doing wrong. I am most likely overlooking something simple, but for the life of me i cannot figure it out. Can someone help me out and tell me what i am doing wrong? If i am completely wrong in how i am going about to achieve my goal, can you please explain why? The explanation for me is how i learn best. Thanks again for everyones help.

```
    private void SandC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = false;
        splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;

        string[] lengths = File.ReadAllLines("Units.txt");
        int count=0;
        string[] unitName=new string[count];
        while (!(count==10))
        {
            count++;

            lbLengths.Items.Add(count+"."+" "+lengths[count-1].Split(new Char[]{','})[0]);

        }
   }
    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string orginalunits = tborginalUnits.Text;
        int orginalunits1;
        string desiredunits = tbDesiredunits.Text;
        int desiredunits1;
        string lenghttoConvert = tbConvert.Text;
        double lenghttoConvert1;
        string[] lengths = File.ReadAllLines("Units.txt");
        int count = 0;
        double[] units = new double[count];

        while (!(count == 10))
        {
            count++;

            units[count-1]=Convert.ToDouble(lengths[count - 1].Split(new Char[] { ',' })[1]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `double[units]` in `btnConvert_Click` with length 0:

```
 int count = 0;
 double[] units = new double[count];
```

So when you try to access `units[count-1]` with increasing values of `count` farther down, you get an index out of bounds exception because you are trying to access eg `units[1]`, which doesn't exist. Try using `int count = lengths.Length`, with `Length` giving you the total number of elements in your array: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, I would suggest using a `for`-loop instead of a `while`, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<lengths; i++)
{
    units[i]=Convert.ToDouble(lengths[i].Split(new Char[] { ',' })[1]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, i completely forgot about the ".Length". I swapped out everything with count and now it works great. thanks so much ^_^

Answer (score 3):

In C# indexes start from 0 so lets say you have an array of 10 items the first element of your lengths array would be `lengths[0]` respectively the last one is `lengths[9]` that makes total of 10 items in the array. In your while loops you are going all the way up to the 11th element `count == 10` which is in fact `lengths[10]` where the exception is thrown.

This means that `lengths.Length == 10` is true but the last element is `lengths[9]`

The best way of iterating through arrays is using the foreach loop or for loop for example

```
foreach(string str in lengths)
{
   //.. do something with the string
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
{
  string str = lengths[i];
  //.. do something with the str
}
```

another problem with your code is the following

```
int count = 0;
double[] units = new double[count];
```

What you are doing here is effectively creating an empty double array, an array which has 0 items. So the code that tries to assign value to `units[0]` or `units[1]` for example will throw the same `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

EDIT:

you have to end up with something like this (this is not tested and I've written it "by hand" so it may contain some typos but you'll get the point

```
    private string[] lengths;

    private void SandC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lengths = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Units.txt");

        for (var i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
        {
            var line = lengths[i];
            var s = line.Split(',')[0];
            var itemText = string.Format("{0}.{1}", i + 1, s);
        }
    }

    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you dont need to read those again you've stored the in the private field this.lengths
        // string[] lengths = File.ReadAllLines("Units.txt");

        var units = new double[lengths.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
        {
            var line = lengths[i];
            var s = line.Split(',')[1])
            ;
            units[i] = Convert.ToDouble(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand what your saying, but if that is the reason why the error is getting thrown, then why didnt Visual Studios throw the error when i split the string the first time during the form load event? 
              {
                count++;
                
                lbLengths.Items.Add(count+"."+" "+lengths[count-1].Split(new Char[]{','})[0]);
                
            }

Comment: Because you are using lengths[count - 1] and you probably have a new line character \n\r at the end of the text file so you end up with one more line that makes total of 10 lines in the lengths array. Put a breakpoint after the ReadAllLines method run your program in debug mode and check what's inside the lengths array.

Comment: ok so i was trying to format my code so it would appear neatly like your answer did and i failed at it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include how the code should look like

Comment: @mlc, When i tried implementing your code, I was getting a bunch of errors. Eventually i fixed all of them but then it still wasnt working because the variable "line" didnt exist.

Comment: Edited, try it out again.

Comment: @mlc, its working now got it, thanks a lot man, i really do appreciate it. Maybe one day ill be able to return the favor !!!!

Comment: You can return the favour by accepting this as an answer ;) good luck with the learning